# Edge connect like in 3dsmax

Tags: modeling, edges

Is there something simmiliar in Blender to the "Connect Edges" feature in 3dsmax?

[image]

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-57E3DDC9-50D2-4467-93E9-B1B103CEA30D-htm.html

Comment: Yes, if you subdivide the selected edges, you will get the same result, Ctrl+E>Subdivide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve a similar result with the *Subdivide* operator

Just select the desired edges, press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*. In the operator panel options choose the number of cuts.

[image: Edge Subdivide]

Have in mind that this is most likely to create lots of NGons at the ends which are largely considered a bad modelling practice, and prone to problems with topology, animation, and texturing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - i found this this morning, after discovering the loop cut and slide function. 
Subdivide comes close - but its lacking some of these positioning options to get the results closer together or further apart, or some sort of sliding along parent edges.

i come from arch-viz, so bad modelling might be true, but it can give you fast results adding some sort of elements to an facades, as like windows etc. have not discovered any problems regarding the rendering so far.