# Adding edge loops based on selected edges

Tags: edges

I am trying to create edge loops based on a selection. The best way to explain is through the video I am following for learning topology.

https://youtu.be/CpSAG85Rsk0?t=1461
(It is linked at the relevant time in the video)

This shows how it is done in 3DS MAX, which is what I normally use, but I'm trying to learn blender. How can this be done in blender?

Also how can one create two edge loops, and slide them apart, like the pinch function in 3ds max which is also shown in the video, he places them a bit further apart.

EDIT: [Here is a gif](https://i.imgur.com/wjJKGrq.gifv) of what I want to do. After I subdivide, I want to be able to slide the edges apart from each other (like I am doing) but where they follow the mesh' topology.

Comment: In the video first he selects ring of edges and then subdivides them. In Blender this is possible by selecting ring of edges (Ctrl+Alt+LMB) and then pressing W > Subdivide. Loopcuts are added with Ctrl+R but they won't take selection into account rather than topology flow. To change placing of the edge loops look through options of the Loopcut and Slide on the Last Operator panel on the Toolshelf or F6 just after executing command but they won't be absolutely the same as in max.

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75195/edge-connect-like-in-3dsmax and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/can-i-subdivide-vertices-in-a-single-direction

Comment: The subdivisions are neat, that is halfway what I was looking for. But I am unable to slide the edges like he does in the video, is there any way to do that, so that all edges are moved equal amounts?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't slide both edge loops independently away from each other, it slides them together.

Comment: The way to get scaling when object is not oriented along global axes is to scale along local or normal axes, like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/how-to-scale-along-the-local-axis-of-an-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might not like this answer, because I am using face selection instead of Edge Selection, but I do believe that the end result is what you are after, so I'm adding this to your realm of possibilities into achieving your desired end result.

[image]

In face select mode, I achieved this by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right clicking the bottom edge of the face loop, then for successive loop selections adding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to add more loops.

Next I used the <kbd>I</kbd> key to do a face inset, and then I just moved my mouse in and out until I had the desired result, however, you can enter a numeric value instead for the amount of inset.

Comment: Yes, this is a perfectly valid solution! Although it requires me to do some parts individually it works like a charm. Thank you very much! That being said I hope blender one day get's the same "pinching" functionality as 3DS MAX has, as it really is essential for some situations like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work for the slanted faces as far as I can tell.

Comment: @bertmoog your point is related to a topology methodology and discipline. If you look at the model I have posted as a demonstration, it would work perfectly, the loops would just go around horizontally.

Comment: I attempted this before I commented and I couldn't make it work.  Your gif only shows the horizontal sections.  I would love to know how to make this work for the diagonal sections because that's the whole issue.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already shown, the only solution to create edge loops from a selection is Subdivide.

But for the second part, you can scale the edge loops using the ***Normal*** Transform Orientation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I like the idea and it should work. My problem though is that I would like to be able to do that for several different edge loops on different part of the model at the same time. I should mention that I want to do this so that I can add "supporting edges" for my subdivision smoothing of the model. [Here is a gif of what I mean.](http://i.imgur.com/I7HyZcO.gifv)

Comment: Yes, I know, that would be really nice.  If you're doing this just to round the corners, you can always select the corner edges (inside and outside) and do Ctrl+B.

Comment: @MathiasRødeEsmann it's possible to scale multiple edge loops although a bit not directly. Once added several loop pairs select them and switch selection mode to Vertex; faces in between will be selected. Then change Pivot to Individual Origins and scale.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me either as it causes some unwanted bending [as seen here.](http://imgur.com/a/7Bn7F)

Comment: @Mr. Zak - Will that scale properly when not scaling on an axis?

Comment: @bertmoog not for multiple edge loops afaik, maybe a bug or limitation

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're wanting a loop cut in blender! This can be done with CTRL+R, selecting the loop direction with the cursor and scrolling to select the number of cuts. Now, when you click, you can move the mouse or input a number for the loop to be offset from the center of the mesh. Here's what it looks like in use:[image]

I'm not sure what the pinch function does, can you describe or provide a screenshot of it in use so I can find a similar function in Blender?

Comment: Could you crop screenshots only to relevant area? It would help focusing especially for those who aren't really experienced. Small correction is that shortcut for the loopsut is Ctrl+R.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm asking for. I know how to do loop cuts with CTRL+R, but I want to be able to make several loop cuts on the model in different places at the same time, and then slide them all at the same time. Look at the video, that Is what i'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry I meant to correct that shortcut but I forgot. This was at least the closest thing I could find to what I saw in the video. I'm not familiar 3DS Max, so it was a bit hard to follow what he was doing. Sorry I couldn't help

Answer (score 0):

Loop cut and slide (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), and with the loop selected scale to 0 on the relevant axis by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>, then axis (<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd>) then <kbd>0</kbd>. This will make your loop flat on that axis.